# 2-step authentication calling me in Thai. I don't speak Thai.

Tags: localization, 2-step-verification

I setup google 2-step authentication through Google Apps.

I linked my Skype number by Voice instead of SMS.  SMS wasn't going through.  It's a US number.

I'm trying to login on my Android phone in Thailand.  I bought the phone in Thailand with a Thai sim.  I set the Android language to English.

2-step is calling me and giving the number in Thai.  I don't speak Thai.

There's no obvious setting to change the language of "Google sign-in" app on the phone.

I looked in the Domain Admin app and didn't see a setting to change the language.  It's pretty frustrating.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I looked on Wikipedia to translate just the numbers out of the call.  Not so hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you took a copy of **Backup Codes** which are provided while enabling *2-Step Verification*? They can help you to login if you've them.

Otherwise, try resetting your password. That's the only option left. And, from the next time install the **Google Authenticator** App from PlayStore as it creates code by itself and comes very handy. No reliance on SMS/Call.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2&hl=en